# How to transfer a lot of variables to a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass many variables to a javascript function? I would like to simplify my code. It is much too long if I have to write an extra function for each variable. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('#item1').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
    }, 2000, function () {
        revapi8.revcallslidewithid('item-11');;
    });
});

$('#item2').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div2").offset().top
    }, 2000, function () {
        revapi8.revcallslidewithid('item-12');;
    });
});

$('#item3').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div3").offset().top
    }, 2000, function () {
        revapi8.revcallslidewithid('item-13');;
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Which function you are talking about? Why not use classes for attaching similar events to different elements?

Comment: why don't you pass it as array or object

Comment: Best way to do that is using objects, as in `{name1: value1, name2: value2, name3: value3}` and then just passing that object to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your elements are as provided in question. This approach will work for you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var arr = [1,2,3]; //element iterator
  arr.forEach(function(item){
    $('#item' + item).click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div" + item).offset().top
      }, 2000, function() {
        revapi8.revcallslidewithid('item-1' + item);;
      });
    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-*` prefix cutsom attribute to persists arbitary data with element which can be accessed using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) or [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

Assign a CSS class i.e. `item` then use [Class Selector `(".class")`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to bind event handler

*HTML*

```
<div class='item' data-related-div="#div1" data-related-item="item-11">item 1</div>
<div class='item' data-related-div="#div2" data-related-item="item-12">item 2</div>
<div class='item' data-related-div="#div3" data-related-item="item-13">item 3</div>
```

*Script*

```
$('.item').click(function () {
    var div =  $(this).data('relatedDiv');//this.dataset.relatedDiv
    var item =  $(this).data('relatedItem');//this.dataset.relatedItem
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(div).offset().top
    }, 2000, function () {
        revapi8.revcallslidewithid(item);;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simple use the jQuery `index()` method to get the clicked elements index and use the `get()` method to get the corresponding div element. This will of course only work if the amount of clickable elements is equal to the div elements you want to scroll to.

Here is an example.

```js
var $body = $('html, body');
var $itemsWrap = $('#items-wrap');
var $items = $itemsWrap.find('.item');
var $divs = $('[id^="div"]');

$itemsWrap.on( 'click', function(evt) {
  var index = $items.index( evt.target );
  $body.animate({ scrollTop: $($divs.get(index)).offset().top }, 666);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


div[id^="div"] {
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="items-wrap">
  <button class="item">item-1</button>
  <button class="item">item-2</button>
  <button class="item">item-3</button>
</div>

<div id="div1"><h1>Div 1</h1></div>
<div id="div2"><h1>Div 2</h1></div>
<div id="div3"><h1>Div 3</h1></div>
```